# JSONDecodeError when trying to call REST api in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to access the opensecrets.org api to get some information on congress members. I am trying to access all rows in the database for each member of congress, which I have in my ID's, and append them to a dataframe for manipulation.

Here's my code:

```
new_house_df = pd.DataFrame([])

for row in house_crp_id:
    r = requests.get('http://www.opensecrets.org/api/?method=candSummary&cid=' + row + 
                     '&cycle=2022&apikey=' + my_key)
    data = r.json()
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['candSummary'])
    new_house_df = new_house_df.append(df_temp, ignore_index = True, sort = False)
```

Which is producing this error at `data = r.json()`

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

---

Here is a sample output from the api.
[image]

I'm searching through stackoverflow but not finding anything explaining what the problem is within my code, or if it's a problem with opensecrets api.

Here is the documentation if it helps. https://www.opensecrets.org/open-data/api-documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix headers and use `output=json`:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
data = requests.get('http://www.opensecrets.org/api/...?...output=json', headers=headers)
```

Comment: after adding `output=json` it threw a 400 code (bad request) at me. Is there a specific way you add that to the call? Apologies, still slightly new to all of this. Thank you!

Comment: In the documentation you can explicitly set `output=json` (or `xml`). if you remove output=json and use only headers, does it work?

Comment: Try https://github.com/robrem/opensecrets-crpapi

Comment: This ended up working; thank you! I had specified it earlier in some code and it was still displaying an error, so that fixes a lot of it!